# RegExp for a bash script that removes html garbage from a string

Tags: html, regex, bash

For several reason i get the output from a script that crawl an html page with some extra html code that i don't need.

Here's what i've:

```
... MY DATA IN A SINGLE ROW FOLLOWED BY ...> <script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><style> html .fb_share_button { display: -moz-inline-block; display:inline; padding:1px 11px 0 5px; height:15px; border:1px solid #d8dfea; background:url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top right; } html .fb_share_button:hover { color:#fff; border-color:#295582; background:#3b5998 url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top right; text-decoration:none; } </style> <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=/dizionario/recensi ne.asp?id=11334" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
```

Perhaps this extra code could be stripped out with a REGEXP that removes all the content of the string next to the  tag and the tag included..

Comment: Is your data always followed by `...>` or this just a symbol you have used here for illustration ?

Comment: just for illustration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing html tags (and script, and style) is not always easy with regex, but since you are looking for a bash way, you can use a simple trick: using a text browser (lynx, links, w3m), example:

```
lynx -dump input.html > output.txt
```

Or you can use the inline tool [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) with an XPath query:

```
xidel ./input.html --extract "//text()[not(parent::style|parent::script)]"
```

You can try with regex too, but it is less safer:

```
sed 's/<script.*<\/script>\|<style.*<\/style>\|<[^>]*>//g' input.html
```

(note that this regex fails with something like: `<script>sfsdfsfsdf</script> CONTENT <script>sdfsdfsdf</script>`)

or you can use this regex that is a little more safer in an html context:

```
sed -r 's/<script([^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^c])*<\/script>|<style([^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^t])*<\/style>|<[^>]*>//g' input.html
```

You can easily preserve tags like "a" and "strong" by adding a capturing group before the last case (i.e. `|<[^>]*>`):

```
|(<a ([^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^a]|<\/a[^>])*<\/a>|<strong([^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^t]|<\/st[^r])*<\/strong>)
```

and then change the replacement pattern by `$3` (it's the third group of the pattern)

Comment: Thanks Casimir, unfortunally i've to strip only certain tags from the text, (i.e. script and garbage) because i need to clean the content but i've to mantain the <a> links in the html and the <strong>.

That's why i can't use lynx or w3m to strip the html, but the regexp that you've wrote works very well..